# Assign keyboard shortcut to change network environment

Tags: keyboard, network, shortcut, menu-bar

How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to change the network environment?
They networks are accessible under `Apple menu → Environment → [name]`.

I wish want to quickly switch between the wired and the wireless network environment without leaving the keyboard.

[image]

**UPDATE**: I assigned the shortcuts under Keyboard System Preference, but pressing the assigned keys does except generating error sound. The shortcuts are assigned as shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried key shortcuts in system preferences?

Comment: yes, I added "Umgebung->LAN" to the shortcuts under the section "All applications". It does not work... even though it correctly assigned it... (see updated question)

Comment: Sorry, on a smartphone - just an idea - someone else will be along probably.

Comment: → It now works... don't know why.. Maybe you have to close System preferences to have macOS actually assign the shortcut.. Thanks!

Comment: Magic! Have a good day!

Comment: If you write this up as an answer, I'll vote for it...